# iteration over each word in array

Tags: ruby, file

I have a very big .txt file and i want to write a ruby script to filter through some data. Basically I want to iterate over each line and then store the individual words in the line in an array and then operate on the words. however I am not able to get each word separately in a array

```
tracker_file.each_line do|line|
arr = "#{line}"
```

I can get the entire line like this but how about the individual words?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use the `split` method on a string.

```
irb(main):001:0> line = "one two three"
=> "one two three"
irb(main):002:0> line.split
=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

So your example would be:

```
tracker_file.each_line do |line|
  arr = line.split
  # ... do stuff with arr
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tracker_file.each_line do |line|
  line.scan(/[\w']+/) do |word|
    ...
  end
end
```

If you do not need to iterate over lines, you can directly iterate over words:

```
tracker_file.read.scan(/[\w']+/) do |word|
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
tracker_file.each_line do |line|
    arr = line.split
# Then perform operations on the array
end
```

The `split` method will split a string into an array based on a delimiter, in this case, a space.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading something written in English and the text may contain hyphens, semicolons, spaces, periods, etc. you might consider a regular expression, such as the following:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+(\-[a-zA-Z]+)*/
```

to extract the words instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `IO#each_line`, you could also use `IO#each(separator_string)`

Another option is to use `IO#gets`:

```
while word = tracker_file.gets(/separator_regexp/)
  # use the word
end
```